# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'ThunkAction<Promise<string>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, typescript-typings, redux-thunk

I am getting the error

```
Property 'then' does not exist on type 'ThunkAction<Promise<string>
```

I am trying to return a promise from a AppThunk in my slice.

below is the code I have setup and I have went through several same questions and followed few suggestions given there, but still could not figure out what is wrong.

store.ts

```typescript
import { configureStore, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducer, { RootState } from './rootReducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
})

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./rootReducer', () => {
    const newRootReducer = require('./rootReducer').default
    store.replaceReducer(newRootReducer)
  })
}

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()


export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>

export default store
```

mySlice.ts

```typescript
import { AppThunk } from 'app/store'

// ...
// my reducer logic is here 
// ...

export const fetchIssuePromise = (): AppThunk<Promise<string>> => async (dispatch) => {
  return Promise.resolve("string")
}
```

and I am using this in my component.

MyComponent.tsx

```typescript
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { fetchIssue, fetchIssuePromise } from 'features/mySlice.ts'
import {  useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

export const MyComponent = ({
const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(fetchIssuePromise()).then(() => {
      // My logic here.
      })
  }, [dispatch])
  
  
})
```

I know I can do this by storing in redux state and using selector and work on that.
But I do not want to store some data especially validation errors from server in redux.

I am not sure if this approach is correct, please let me know how can I handle this or any better ways to achieve this.

Comment: There is another question about this which I cannot find at the moment, but basically it's a legitimate mistake in the redux-thunk types package and there is a GitHub issue about it.  A normal dispatch doesn't return anything but the thunk dispatch is supposed to return the value.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use the default "useDispatch" hook.

As mentionned in this github issue: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/678

The linked doc: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type

In your store.ts:

```
    export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
    export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
    export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
```

In your Component.tsx:

```
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch() // hook exported from store
```